# Fetching data in next js 13 production

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have the following code in my next js api.

**api/home/route.ts**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import API from "@/lib/axios"

export async function GET(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const response = await API.get("/landing")
    return NextResponse.json(response.data)
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error)

    return NextResponse.json({ message: error.message }, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

i'm using it as:

**lib/utils.ts**

```
export async function fetchData(path: string) {
  let url

  if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "local") {
    url = "http://localhost:3000" + path
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    // Production environment
    url = path
  }
  const response = await fetch(`${url}`)
  return await response.json()
}
```

And in my landing page

```
import { fetchData } from "@/lib/utils"

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await fetchData("/api/home")
}
```

With the above code the app runs fine in local (yarn dev) and running yarn build is also success in local.

But when deployed in vercel. The build process is failing with error message:

[image: Build error message]

I've used similar approach in my contact page also. Where I've created a api route (/api/contact) which accepts post request. And send request to my laravel backend server to send email.

The api route (/api/contact) is triggered when contact form is filled and submitted.

I couldn't figure out why my app is failing in vercel for deployment. What is the best approach to make POST and GET request to external server. I want to avoid the use of server action since it is experimental.

Comment: Where do you define `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` and `process.env.NODE_ENV`? Do you have a `.env*` file?

Comment: I define them in .env file and have set value to "local" in my pc. In vercel it has value "production". I have not used NODE_ENV

Comment: Do you have a github repo with this code?

Comment: It's a private repo of a client

Comment: Do you fetch in server component or client?

Comment: Home is a server component. Contact form page is also server component. But the form section is extracted to client component. i.e components/ContactForm.tsx

Comment: @psudo So `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` is `production` on vercel and `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not set. So `url` is undefined. That would explain your error.